# VirtualHost with localhost

Tags: dart

I would use sub-domain, for this, I'm trying to use this code:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:http_server/http_server.dart';

void main() {
    HttpServer.bind('localhost', 8080).then((server) {
        final virtualServer = new VirtualHost(server);
        virtualServer.addHost('test.mydomain.com').listen((HttpRequest req) {
            print('Got it');
        });
    });
}
```

I go on `test.mydomain.com:8080`, and maybe because it's normal, this doesn't work.

Where I'm wrong ? It's the way to use it, or my code ? And how fix it ?

Comment: Does `test.mydomain.com` actually resolve to your IP address? Seing as you bind the server to `localhost`, I kinda doubt it. Or maybe this very binding is your problem?

Comment: Bleh. Stupid 5min comment edit window. What I was trying to formulate: Does `test.mydomain.com` actually resolve to the IP address the server is running on? Also, as you are binding the server to `localhost`, this IP address would have to be 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding your domain to the [hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file

Answer (score 1):

As JAre has mentioned above add your subdomains to your hosts file (in my case on OSX in /etc/hosts):

```
127.0.0.1 test.mydomain.com
127.0.0.1 test2.mydomain.com
```